# Matlab Genetic Algorithm (GA) using only unique integers

Tags: matlab, optimization, integer, constraints, genetic-algorithm

I'm using matlabs GA to optimise an array of integer variables, but I want each variable to be a unique value.
To be more precise, I only want a certain proportion to have unique values.

For example, say I have to find the optimal integer values for 10 variables, but as a requirement my optimisation needs to ensure that the last 5 are all unique values between a given range. How would I go about ensuring that the last 5 variables are unique?

I was thinking of using a non-linear constraint that flags up any repeated variables but this will mean that the GA will still run this iteration which will cause an error. Another way I was thinking of, but not sure how to do it, would be to create a custom creation function that ensure that they are unqiue?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use a setup similar to drawing from a deck in your fitness function?

I.e. say you wanted a 3 unique integers from the range 1-10, instead of trying to tell the GA to select 3 unique integers, tell it to select an **index** between 1 and 10 for the first variable, 1-9 for the second and 1-8 for the third. Pass an array of unique integers between 1 and 10 to your fitness function, either programmatically or using a anonymous function. The first variable selects its integer from this array (by indexing), you then remove this integer from the array. Repeat with the second and third variables. This way each variable selects a unique value (like drawing from a deck of cards).

Comment: That's a nice simple solution. Thanks.